# Facebook share using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I want develop Facebook share on my website using JavaScript.

I have tried:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://example.local/" data-width="500"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=myappid&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

This is working fine,
this is showing DemoUser shared a link,
but I want DemoUser added a review on example.local
and I also wanted to share text box review on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

That would only be possible with Open Graph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started

Not sure what you mean with "textbox review" though.